# JQuery fallback function for CSS3 placeholder

Tags: jquery, css, cross-browser

The following function should ensure that if a device does not have CSS3 abilities that it should be set with a value instead. It does not work. There is no value present in non CSS3 browsers. Here is a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/X9ZZp/2/

```
// Search Input Placeholder 
$(document).ready(function(){
if(!Modernizr.csstransitions) {
    $('#gensearch').val($('#gensearch').attr('plaeholder'));
    $('#gensearch').click(function() {
        $(this).val('');
    });
    $('#gensearch').blur(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('plaeholder'));
        }
    });
}
});
```

Any ideas,

Marvellous

Comment: If you're checking for HTML5 placeholder compatibility, you should be checking for `!Modernizr.input.placeholder` rather than `!Modernizr.csstransitions`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spelling Mistake, Thats Annoying. Sorry Everybody.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(!Modernizr.csstransitions) {
    $('#gensearch').val($('#gensearch').attr('placeholder'));
    $('#gensearch').click(function() {
        $(this).val('');
    });
    $('#gensearch').blur(function() {
        if($(this).val() == '') {
            $(this).val($(this).attr('placeholder'));
        }
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Reworked your example - it works here in IE7

did you know that you can add resources to JSFIDDLE instead of havingto declare them:

[Look at this example](http://jsfiddle.net/X9ZZp/12/)